# gcc compiler option to warn on unused global variables defined outside of main in C

Tags: c, gcc, compiler-warnings

```
# include <stdio.h>
# include <stdlib.h>

int myvariable_NOT_caught_by_Wall;

int main ( int argc, char *argv[] )
{
   int myvariable_caught_by_Wall;

   return 0;
}
```

is it normal for gcc when compiling via **gcc some_program.c -Wall** for no 
warning to be issued for unused global variables?

Is there a way to make that happen?
I've experienced this using gcc-4.3.4 and gcc-4.8.3 in SLES_11.4

Comment: It has external linkage. What if you link it against an object that *does* use it?

Comment: If that global is declared `static` then it won't have external linkage, so then gcc might warn if it's unused.  It may also vary by whether you're compiling with `-c`...i.e., whether the compiler can assume it has seen all the relevant sources.

Comment: sorry should've said just a single **some_program.c** file.  There would be no external linkage; program is written quickly so some shortcuts are taken.  It would just be me writing the program and me running the program 99.9% of the time, to do a fairly simple data processing task that otherwise could be done with a macro in excel with the exception being the data set to be processed is often many gigabytes.

Comment: i will define some global variables outside of `int main ( int argc, char *argv[] )` when I need a very large array for example that would exceed the ~8mb stacksize limit in `/etc/security/limits.conf`and it's not worth dynamically allocating the array via `calloc`

Comment: @ron  There is very likely an external linkage against glibc... Because programs can override `weak` symbols in libraries, there is no way for the compiler to know, whether it is such a variable or whether you wanted to declare it `static`. Unfortunately,  `-Wmissing-prototypes` catches function declarations only, not variables.

Answer (score 3):

> is it normal for gcc when compiling via gcc some_program.c -Wall for no warning to be issued for unused global variables?

Yes.

The compiler cannot know at compile time that the global variable is not used.

Imagine another .c file:

```
extern int myvariable_NOT_caught_by_Wall;

void foo()
{
   if (myvariable_NOT_caught_by_Wall == 0 )
   {
      dothis();
   }
   else
   {
      dothat();
   }
}
```

Comment: And the solution to this is to make it `static`. The compiler will then warn about it.

Comment: Supposedly, -fwhole-program or -flto could make it warn (not sure if that would be a good idea though), but it doesn't.

Answer (score 0):

thanks to the guy who said **static**  that does what I am specifically looking for.  I do not want to use other compile options besides `-O2 -Wall` if I don't have to.

and my goal is to simply have **one** .c file written, and I need to write it quickly, to do a particular data processing task, where it's not worth the effort to do extra writing of code using `malloc()` and `calloc()` and `free()` when I can simply do a global outside of main() such as `double myarray[5][2][10][3600][9000][2];`

*if you are wondering, it's for storing some signal data dumped to a text file, I can have up to 9000 samples or more for each look angle where it's*

[#elevation_angles] [polarization h or v] [#frequencies] [#az_angles][#samples] [i or q]

```
# include <stdio.h>
# include <stdlib.h>

static int myvariable_NOW_caught_by_Wall;  /* -Wall catches this when static */

int main ( int argc, char *argv[] )
{
   int myvariable_caught_by_Wall;

   return 0;
}
```